# SQL Stored Procedure Parameters Being Assigned to Variables

Tags: sql

I'm sure there is some sound logic/best practice but I'd like it explained to me if possible. Looking at SQL stored procedures written by a previous employee he always declares 1 variable for each parameter and sets the variable equal to the parameter value and then uses the variable throughout the remainder of the stored procedure. What is the added value in not just using the parameter vs assigning to a variable?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_shipping]
(
@p_date varchar(10),
@p_status varchar(10),
@p_cust nvarchar(20)
)
as

set nocount on

declare @v_date datetime,
        @v_status varchar(10),
        @v_cust nvarchar(20)

select @v_date = convert(datetime,@p_date),
       @v_status = @p_status,
       @v_cust = @p_cust
```

Comment: It worths to recognize just by the name if you are working with a variable or with a parameter.

Comment: Very likely a preference thing? I personally don't like extra variables, but others do. I can only guess that the `@p_` are parameter-related, and the `@v_` for the values from those parameters. The `@v_date` makes since for having that value converted once, instead of multiple convert calls on the parameter value throughout the procedure. (don't know how often v_date is used, though) Assuming no set team `coding standard`, you could code however you'd like. (or maybe something to have a team discussion about -- could definitely make less code-clutter, which is what it seems you'd like to see)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, I get the value behind the @date as a "set it and forget it" kinda tactic. I still dont know that I would have declared it as a new variable though I'm a very OCD person in my coding and life. To me the fewer lines of code the better. I was fully expecting comments like "You dummy. You should always convert your parameters to variables because of XYZ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely just a preference/style but it is worth noting that it does have an impact on the @p_date variable,

```
select @v_date = convert(datetime,@p_date)
```

This will throw an error if it is unable to convert the parameter to a datetime and it stores the result of the conversion so you don't have to repeat it later in the stored procedure.